# How to adduser when using debian as a base image

Tags: docker, debian, forgerock

I am trying to add an system user from my docker file and i am not able to do that.

I am getting this error every time:

```
adduser: Only one or two names allowed.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install unzip curl bash vim dnsutils tini     && rm -fr "$CATALINA_HOME"/webapps/ROOT     && mkdir -p /opt/forgerock     && addgroup --gid 11111 forgerock     && adduser /bin/bash --system --home "$FORGEROCK_HOME" --uid 11111 --group root --disabled-password forgerock     && chown -R forgerock:root "$CATALINA_HOME" "$FORGEROCK_HOME"     && chmod -R g+rwx "$CATALINA_HOME"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The part from docker file where i try to do this is the following:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install unzip curl bash vim dnsutils iputils-ping tini \
&& rm -fr "$CATALINA_HOME"/webapps/ROOT \
&& mkdir -p /opt/forgerock \
&& addgroup --gid 11111 forgerock \
&& adduser /bin/bash --system --home "$FORGEROCK_HOME" --uid 11111 --group root --disabled-password forgerock \
&& chown -R forgerock:root "$CATALINA_HOME" "$FORGEROCK_HOME" \
&& chmod -R g+rwx "$CATALINA_HOME"
```

Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're running `adduser /bin/bash ... forgerock`.  Are you forgetting a `--shell` option (or can you remove that option entirely)?

Comment: The thing is that i try to modify a docker file that is base on an alpine base image into a docker file that will be based on an debian base image and i am new to this. So if you can guide me a little bit will be very helpful. What should i modify in my command?

Comment: The documentation for `adduser` tells you what the options mean and how to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian uses the command **useradd** and **usergroup** for creating users and groups (rather than **adduser** and **addgroup**).

I modified your Dockerfile snippet to relate with Debian commands:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install unzip curl bash vim dnsutils iputils-ping tini \
&& rm -fr "$CATALINA_HOME"/webapps/ROOT \
&& mkdir -p /opt/forgerock \
&& groupadd -f -g 11111 forgerock \
&& useradd -l -u 11111 -g root -d "$FORGEROCK_HOME" -r forgerock \
&& chown -R forgerock:root "$CATALINA_HOME" "$FORGEROCK_HOME" \
&& chmod -R g+rwx "$CATALINA_HOME"
```

Comment: Thk man...this is working now!